# Would a transition from liquid metal to solid metal hydrogen exhibit thermodynamic characteristics of freezing?

Tags: phase-transition, hydrogen, metals

Hydrogen is proposed to have (at least) two metallic states. I believe the liquid metal state [has been observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_hydrogen#Observation_of_liquid_metallic_hydrogen.2C_2011) for a short time under high pressure and temperature conditions, and solid metal hydrogen [may have been observed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308155/83380) at high pressure but a lower temperature.

Can one think of the difference between liquid metal hydrogen and at least some predicted form of solid metal hydrogen as the freezing of the protons from a fluid to a solid, with the protons resting on a lattice within the electron gas?

**edit:** In [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/255155/83380) by @RobJeffries about electron degeneracy in solid metal hydrogen the above is addressed - indeed it can make sense to think of the transition in those terms, so I'd like to modify my question to ask, roughly speaking, "how much like freezing" might that transition be:

If a transition between the liquid metal and some solid metal form of hydrogen occurs, would it exhibit similar thermodynamic characteristics of normal crystallization? For example, at a given pressure would there be a well defined transition temperature and energy (e.g. freezing temperature, heat of fusion) and phenomena like nucleation?

I'm guessing the answer may be yes again. [This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/255090/83380) by @floris discusses the transition and a phase diagram in [Everything about Hydrogen](https://hydropole.ch/en/hydrogen/abouth2/) linked there, and mentions a certain fuzziness.

[image]

**above:** Screen shot from [Everything about Hydrogen](https://hydropole.ch/en/hydrogen/abouth2/) in which reference (12) is: [W. B. Leung and N. H. March H. Motz, “Primitive Phase Diagram for Hydrogen”, Physics Letters 56A, 6 (1976), pp. 425-426](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0375960176907131) (also [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1976PhLA...56..425L))

**Abstract:**

> Using a combination of experimental data, empirical rules and extrapolation formula, plus first principles theory, the major phase boundaries are drawn in the phase diagram of hydrogen. The relevance to laser fusion is briefly referred to.

Comment: Is it any different from the difference between liquid metal iron and solid metal iron?

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255082/what-is-the-difference-between-metallic-hydrogen-and-plasma-of-hydrogen/255155#255155

Comment: @RobJeffries OK well it doesn't get much more "yes" than that! It turns out I've read part of your answer yesterday and [linked to it](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20288/#comment54459_20290) but missed what you've written about "freezing". Thanks for pointing this out. I've modified the question to take it a step further.